# Scala Lift - Convert model list to json object list

Tags: json, scala, model, lift

I have the following model

```
class User private() extends MongoRecord[User] with ObjectIdPk[User] {

    def meta = User

    object name extends StringField(this, 50)
    object level extends StringField(this, 50)

}

object User extends User with MongoMetaRecord[User]
```

And am loading a list of users via:

```
val users = User.findAll(

    ("room" -> "demo")

)
```

What I'm trying to do is convert the list of users loaded into something like:

```
var users = [

    {"name": "James", "level" : "_1"},
    {"name": "Jim", "level" : "_2"},
    {"name": "Anon1", "level" : "_2"},
    {"name": "Anon2", "level" : "_2"} 

];
```

I've tried the following, which produced the right number of objects in the list but with empty values:

```
write(users)
```

And the result:

```
[{},{},{},{}]
```

Thanks in advance for any help, much appreciated :)

Comment: I've edited the question to be more clear :)

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with the APIs in use but assuming one user can be Json serialized like:

```
val serUser = write(someUser)
```

then could you do

```
users.map(write)
```